# Handling alert/dialogue box when you are not sure about their time of occurrence

Tags: selenium, protractor

Is there a way to handle dialogue box that are displayed due to some background check the system keeps doing.

Ex: I have a async job that is running and on its completion it throws an alert that its done and it blocks the rest of the window until I click ok on it, because of this my rest of the tests starts to fail.

Looking for something like if you don’t find the element you are looking  for , for more than 3 secs then check if some alert box is present.

Comment: Cheap hack would be to write your own custom function to wrap the element() and element.all() methods. Check if the modal alert box is present, if so do the alert processing. Then call the original element() and element.all() methods.   The biggest problem is what happens in other scenarios like alert appears before a button is going to be clicked, mouse move, send keys to some input. Is the async job result impact your test? If not is there someway of disabling the alert functionality like setting some value of a cookie etc?

Comment: Developers helped me out, to stop the async job through a boolean value in config file.